# Can't Shake MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

So I have a very fun issue. I tried to reset my MySQL password, and then I was locked out of MySQL. No biggie, I can just uninstall MySQL, right?

Wrong.

I ran:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql-client mysql-server mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
```

But I got this issue after about 10 minutes of installation:

```
   │ Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user                                                          │ 
   │                                                                                                           │ 
   │ An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened    │ 
   │ because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL server.  │ 
   │                                                                                                           │ 
   │ You should check the account's password after the package installation.                                   │ 
   │                                                                                                           │ 
   │ Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more information.
```

How can I remove MySQL properly so that I can install it fresh?

Comment: try if this helps: http://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just removing the configuration files. You'll need to remove the database(s) as well.

Those are often stored in `/var/lib/mysql` or something similar.

Comment: Ah, yeah google searching `uninstall mysql ubuntu` didn't tell me that. I'll try it and get back to you

Comment: This should work, but I am sure there should be another solution without having to lose your data, or exporting and importing... I know the OP maybe doesn't care now but just out of curiosity.

Comment: @CodeBird I had 2 tables with test data, I'm not worried about data preservation :)

Comment: @RUJordan I know you don't care, but just curious if this is really the only solution, like imagine yourself in the same case with 10 large tables with useful info. They surely thought about that while building mysql :)

Comment: @CodeBird You can boot MySQL with the `--skip-grants` option to [reset the root password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html) if you care about retaining the data.

Comment: yep that's the link I posted in my comment, wasn't sure it works though never tried it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @codebird I've had to use it several times and it works great. Just remember to restart with **permissions back on** unless you think it's fantastic that no passwords to your database are required. Probably a bad thing  to do long-term!

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the /var/lib/mysql folder.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
```

I previously had similar issues. The last line helped me. I hope it helps you too.